# Looking for a specific playmat

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was at the prerelease this weekend and someone had a mat that a friend of mine mentioned that he wanted. I tried some googling, but didn't have much success and was hoping someone here might recognize the description and be able to recognize it.

It was a blue mat, with some sort of blue sun that was very bright in the middle, and a blue ice-like surface of a planet in the bottom left corner, the edge of the planet surface being a straight line from left edge of the mat to the bottom. Additionally, it had a life counting section on the right hand side.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a playmat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it this one? It was found pretty fast by me just by googling "magic playmat blue". It is the art of [glacial fortress](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bglacial%20fortress%5d) so if you google that you probably find places where you can buy it.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. I spent 3 hours with various search queries without any luck. Many thanks!